# multiple file uploaded not working in php

Tags: html, forms, file, file-upload

```
<?php
 include 'database_connector.php';
 session_start();
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){  
 $cat=$_POST['cat'];
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $date=$_POST['date'];
 $time=$_POST['time'];
 $lat=$_POST['lat'];
 $long=$_POST['long'];
 $speed=$_POST['wind'];
 $direct=$_POST['direction'];
 $move=$_POST['speed'];
 $pressure=$_POST['pressure'];
 $threedaycone=$_POST['3daycone'];
 $fivedaycone=$_POST['5daycone'];
 $uploaddir='uploads/';
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["name"]);
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $check = getimagesize($_FILES["tmp_name"]);
 $result=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `Spots`(`ID`, `DATE`, `NAME`, `TIME`, `LONG`, `LAT`, `WINDSPEED`, `DIRECTION`, `MOVEMENT`, `PRESSURE`, `CATAGORY`) VALUES ('','$date','$name','$time','$lat','$long','$speed','$direct','$move','$pressure','$cat')");
 if($result){ print "Coordinates added"; header("location:users.php");}
 else{print "Coordinates not added"; }
 if(isset($fivedaycone)) {
 $check = getimagesize($_FILES["5daycone"]["tmp_name"]);
 if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
//header( "refresh:5;url=add.php" );
 }
 }
 // Check if file already exists
     if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
     //header( "refresh:5;url=add.php" );
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
 if ($_FILES["size"] > 5000000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
//header( "refresh:5;url=addp.php" );
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
   if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
header( "refresh:5;url=add.php" );
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} 
else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["5daycone"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/5daycone/")) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["5daycone"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    $result2=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `5daycone`(`id`, `name`, `type`, `size`, `content``) VALUES ('','$target_file','$imageFileType','$check','')");
    header('location: users.php');
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
header("location: add.php");
}
}

 }
```

This is my html code for the form. I am trying to upload a sets of pictures for each submission. This is a hurricane tracking site I did last year but did not do the form upload. I took out the 3daycode since it is the same information that the 5daycone has.

```
<html>
<form action="add.php" name="add" method="post" id="addform">
    <table class="table-addform" cellspacing="1px" width="75%">
        <tr>
            <td>Catagory Type:(TD, TS, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5)</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="cat" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name of Storm:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:(yyyy-mm-dd)</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="date"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Time of Update:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="time">
                    <optgroup label="time">
                        <option value="null">Please Choose Time of Update</option>
                        <option value="16:00:00">04:00 PM</option>
                        <option value="17:00:00">05:00 PM</option>
                        <option value="18:00:00">06:00 PM</option>
                        <option value="19:00:00">07:00 PM</option>
                        <option value="20:00:00">08:00 PM</option>
                        <option value="21:00:00">09:00 PM</option>
                        <option value="22:00:00">10:00 PM</option>
                        <option value="23:00:00">11:00 PM</option>
                        <option value="24:00:00">12:00 PM</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Latitude:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lat" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Longitude:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="long" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wind Speed:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="wind" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Direction:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="direction" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Movement:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="speed" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pressure:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="pressure" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3 day cone</td>
            <td>
                <input id="threedaycone" type="file" name="3daycone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5 day cone</td>
            <td>
                <input id="fivedaycone" name="5daycone" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your HTML code, however I am unable to do so for your PHP. I recommend making it easier to read. This will increase your chances of somebody looking at the code in-depth and giving you a helpful answer. You also may want to put some text at the very beginning of the question describing the PHP code that follows.

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="add.php" name="add" method="post" id="addform" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: I added that, it is still not working. Both directories have read/write access